# How to Position a JLabel in the specified Layout?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, layout-manager

I am trying to position my Labels and Button on screen. I found an answer here to set label's Position using: `label3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); label3.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);` but there has been no effect in my code.

Also, on changing my layout from Flow Layout to Border Layout, only one Jbutton [CLEAR] appears on the Screen. Can anyone help me rectify this?

```
public class Corrected1 extends JFrame {

    public JTextField tf1;
    public JTextField tf2;
    public JLabel label1;
    public JLabel label2;
    public JLabel label3;
    public JLabel label4;
    public JButton button1;
    public JButton button2;
    public JComboBox cb,cb1;
    public String[] list={"DOLLARS","EUROS ","YEN","POUNDS","RUPEES"};

    public void init() {try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                 Corrected();
                 }
             });
    } catch (InvocationTargetException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error occured due to "+ exc);
        exc.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException exc1) {
        System.out.println("Error occured due to "+ exc1);

        exc1.printStackTrace();
    }


 }   




public void Corrected(){



    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("FROM  :");
    label1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));

    JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();


    cb= new JComboBox(list);
    cb.getSelectedIndex();

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(label1, gbc);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(cb, gbc);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("TO :");
    label2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    JComboBox cb1 = new JComboBox();
    cb1=new JComboBox(list);
    cb1.getSelectedIndex();

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    add(label2, gbc);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(cb1, gbc);

    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("\n\nENTER THE AMOUNT  :");
    label3.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    label3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label3.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    add(label3, gbc);
    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(15);
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(tf1, gbc);

    JLabel label4 = new JLabel("CONVERTED AMOUNT :");
    label4.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    label4.setDisplayedMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    add(label4, gbc);
    JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(15);
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(tf2, gbc);

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

    JButton button1 = new JButton("CONVERT");
    button1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    button1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_K);
    buttons.add(button1);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("CLEAR ");
    button2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    button2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    buttons.add(button2);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    add(buttons, gbc);

    thehandler handler= new thehandler();

     cb.addActionListener(handler);
     cb1.addActionListener((ActionListener) handler);    
     button1.addActionListener((ActionListener) handler);    
     button2.addActionListener((ActionListener) handler);    
     tf1.addActionListener((ActionListener) handler);    
     tf2.addActionListener((ActionListener) handler);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//pack();
 setSize(450,250);
setVisible(true);

}


public class thehandler implements ActionListener{


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double a=0,b=0; 
        a=Double.valueOf(tf1.getText());
        {
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==0 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==1)
                b=a*0.89;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==0 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==2)
                b=a*124.75;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==0 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==3)
                b=a*0.65;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==0 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==4)
                b=a*64.08;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==1 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==0)
                b=a*1.13;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==1 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==2)
                b=a*140.49;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==1 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==3)
                b=a*0.74;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==1 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==4)
                b=a*71.34;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==2 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==0)
                b=a*0.0080;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==2 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==1)
                b=a*0.0071;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==2 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==3)
                b=a*0.0052;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==2 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==4)
                b=a*0.51;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==3 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==0)
                b=a*1.53;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==3 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==1)
                b=a*1.36;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==3 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==2)
                b=a*191.26;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==3 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==4)
                b=a*97.88;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==4 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==0)
                b=a*0.0156;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==4 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==1)
                b=a*0.014;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==4 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==2)
                b=a*1.9607;
            if(cb.getSelectedIndex()==4 && cb1.getSelectedIndex()==3)
                b=a*0.0108;
            tf2.setText(String.valueOf(b));

        }

        if(e.getSource()==button2){
            tf1.setText("0000");
            tf2.setText("0000");
                        }

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) to understand how it works.

`BorderLayout` will only allow five components to positioned within it, `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, `WEST` and `CENTRE`

By default, components are placed in the `CENTRE` position if you don't otherwise specify.  This means that only the last component added is actually laid out.

`JLabel#setHorizontal/VerticalAlignment` will align the contents of the label when the size of the label is larger, but in the case of `FlowLayout`, it uses the preferred size of the label's content to make decisions about how best to lay it out, so there's generally no extra space

Instead, you could use a `GridBagLayout`, which a one of the more complicated, but flexible layout managers available.

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("FROM  :");
label1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));

JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
add(label1, gbc);
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.gridx++;
add(cb, gbc);

JLabel label2 = new JLabel("TO :");
label2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
JComboBox cb1 = new JComboBox();

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
add(label2, gbc);
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.gridx++;
add(cb1, gbc);

JLabel label3 = new JLabel("\n\nENTER THE AMOUNT  :");
label3.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
label3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
label3.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
add(label3, gbc);
JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(15);
gbc.gridx++;
add(tf1, gbc);

JLabel label4 = new JLabel("CONVERTED AMOUNT :");
label4.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
label4.setDisplayedMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
add(label4, gbc);
JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(15);
gbc.gridx++;
add(tf2, gbc);

JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

JButton button1 = new JButton("CONVERT");
button1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
button1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_K);
buttons.add(button1);

JButton button2 = new JButton("CLEAR ");
button2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
button2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
buttons.add(button2);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
add(buttons, gbc);
```

Sometimes, you even need to combine layouts, which I've done here, using a second `JPanel`, using a `FlowLayout` for the buttons, because it produces the desired result of centring the buttons

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: Someone might like to explain how this doesn't identify the problem the OP is having or provide a means to solve it, so as to attract a downvote?

Comment: interesting once time one of two reasons to stop answering an questions here, I took it quite personally

Comment: Since I don't have source code, theres little I can do

Comment: @MadProgrammer I edited the corrected code , There are no Visible errors but it is not performing the Function.

Answer (score -3):

Components positioning is relative to the layout it belongs to.

If you really want to freely set the position of your `JLabel`'s and `JButton`'s, I advise you to set the layout to null:

`setLayout(null);`

and position the `JLabel` by using the `setBounds()` taking 4 parameters. Dimension of the `JLabel` and its coordinates.

Comment: Null layouts are never the solution and just represent more bad habits and advice that new developers just simply don't need. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify