# How do edit the size of swings?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, size

So, I just need to add *a title* to my swing. Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Wall extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Wall();
    }

    public Wall() {
        final String title = "Wall Game";

        this.setSize(300,300); //sets the screen
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Welcome to the Wall Game!");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Click the button to read the instructions!");
        panel1.add(label1);
        panel1.add(label2);
        this.add(panel1);
    }
}
```

I want the **Welcome to the Wall Game!** part of this to be bigger. Is it possible to make it bigger? If there's a bonus, I wonder if you can add different fonts. But that's not important right now.

Thanks to anyone who knows :P.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the size of the font of a JLabel to take the maximum size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715118/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-font-of-a-jlabel-to-take-the-maximum-size)

Comment: Short answer is, yes, use `JLabel#setFont`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699169/how-to-position-a-jlabel-in-the-specified-layout/30699233#30699233) and loading fonts for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177348/font-awesome-with-swing/24177458#24177458) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081586/using-a-custom-font-for-a-jlabel/21081821#21081821)

Answer (score 2):

I believe all you need is something like this:

```
 JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Welcome to the Wall Game!");
 label1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24));
```

This will set the font to type Arial, '1' will set it to plain, and '24' is the font size.  Just read this if you want to do more with the font:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html

Comment: You can also at the start do "import java.awt.Font". Thx 4 helping out.

Answer (score 1):

```
Font font = new Font("Font Name", Font.TYPE_OF_FONT, size);
yourLabel.setFont(font);
```

Basically, you're creating a "new" font (not really "new" because `Arial` already exists, but you're just making it bigger (deriving it)).

The first parameter: `"Font Name"` is self-explanatory: The name of the font; e.g `Arial`.

The second parameter: `Font.TYPE_OF_FONT` determines what type your font is: for example, `Font.ITALIC` *italicizes* your label. `Font.BOLD` **bolds** your label. For more information, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#field_summary).

The third parameter: `size`, which is, in fact, the size! Changing `size` to 42 makes the font size 42, and changing it to 12345.67890f changes the font size to 12345.67890.

**Applying the font**

`label.setFont(font);`

Pretty self-explanatory.

For more information, read [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html).

Comment: No problem :) Glad to find it could help!